# How to test this line in React with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to reach 100% of test coverage and there's one single line that I simply don't know how to test. Can anyone help me? I'm using Jest, React-testing-library, and ReactJS of course.

I would also appreciate an explanation of how the line was tested since I'm trying to become better at testing.

```
const LatestDataListItem = props => {
  const getThemeTone = useThemeTone(); /* this hooks is simply returning a string(whick can be dark or light) */
  return (
      <StyledItem {...props}>
        <StyledValue
          primaryTextProps={{
            style: {
              fontSize: '32px',
              color: isCaution(props) /* this is what i'm trying to cover */ 
                ? getCautionColorByTheme(getThemeTone).red
                : getCautionColorByTheme(getThemeTone).blue
            }
          }}
        />
      </StyledItem>
  );
};
```

The comment line is what i'm trying to test:

```
color: isCaution(props) 
? getCautionColorByTheme(getThemeTone).red : getCautionColorByTheme(getThemeTone).blue
```

This is the `isCaution` function:

```
const isCaution = ({ caution }) => {
  return true; /* returning true only to make easier to post here */
};
```

And this is the `getCautionColorByTheme`:

```
const colorsByThemeTone = {
  light: {
    blue: '#0d3459',
    red: '#f2463d',
    lightRed: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.07)'
  },
  dark: {
    blue: '#e8e8e8',
    red: '#fa5a4b',
    lightRed: '#fa5a4b'
  }
};

const getCautionColorByTheme = themeTone => {
  return colorsByThemeTone[themeTone];
};
```

So what happens is that the colorsByThemeTone is an object with 2 types: light and dark. getThemeTone returns if the theme is dark or light and this is how I get the colors.

I was thinking that maybe I need to export `getCautionColorByTheme` to import on my `.test.js` file and test this function inside but I don't know how exactly do this.

This is what i tried:

```
  it('should render the test getCautionColorByTheme receiving light theme', () => {
    const colorsByThemeTone = {
      light: {
        blue: '#0d3459',
        red: '#f2463d',
        lightRed: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.07)'
      },
      dark: {
        blue: '#e8e8e8',
        red: '#fa5a4b',
        lightRed: '#fa5a4b'
      }
    };
    const result = getCautionColorByTheme('light');
    expect(result).toMatchObject(colorsByThemeTone.light);
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making the `getCautionColorByTheme()` a pure function:

```
const getCautionColorByTheme = (themeTone) => {
  const colorsByThemeTone = {
    light: {
      blue: '#0d3459',
      red: '#f2463d',
      lightRed: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.07)'
    },
    dark: {
      blue: '#e8e8e8',
      red: '#fa5a4b',
      lightRed: '#fa5a4b'
    }
  };

  return colorsByThemeTone[themeTone];
}
```

or for more flexible implementation (you have to adjust the consumers of `getCautionColorByTheme()`):

```
const getCautionColorByTheme = ({
  themeTone,
  colorsByThemeTone = {
    light: {
    blue: '#0d3459',
    red: '#f2463d',
    lightRed: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.07)'
  },
  dark: {
    blue: '#e8e8e8',
    red: '#fa5a4b',
    lightRed: '#fa5a4b'
  }
 }
}) => colorsByThemeTone[themeTone]
```

And if not already, make `isCaution()` pure too. That way, you can test the logic in isolation.

```
it('should render the test getCautionColorByTheme receiving light theme', () => {
  // should be the same what's the value in getCautionColorByTheme()
  // better if the default value in `getCautionColorByTheme()` is
  // exported as a variable and then used in the test.
  const colorsByThemeTone = {
    light: {
      blue: '#0d3459',
      red: '#f2463d',
      lightRed: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.07)'
    },
    dark: {
      blue: '#e8e8e8',
      red: '#fa5a4b',
      lightRed: '#fa5a4b'
    }
  };

  const result = getCautionColorByTheme('light');

  expect(result).toMatchObject(colorsByThemeTone.light);
});
```

Comment: and how is the conditional operator going to be?

Comment: What do you mean? If you chose the simpler implementation, the condition is still the same. If you go with the more flexible implementation, it'll look like: `color: isCaution(props) ? getCautionColorByTheme({ themeThone: getThemeTone }).red : getCautionColorByTheme({ themeThone: getThemeTone }).blue`

Comment: Its because i'm receiving `Cannot read property 'blue' of undefined`

Comment: You might want to check the value of `getThemeTone` if, it should be either `light` or `dark` if it isn't, there's something wrong with `useThemeTone()`

Comment: It is light by default, since it was working before :(

Comment: Can you share some code snippets, it's hard to know what's wrong without knowing what exactly did you change.